# set Tag property datagridview C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm creating  a datagridview in WinForms. Each cell in the datagridview is either a textboxcell or datagridview image cell. I'm firing a cellMouseDownEent( object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e). If the sected cell is a image cell I perform task1 and if it is textboxcell  I perform task2. I'm not getting how to find out whether the current cell is image cell or text box cell. I tried setting tag property of image cell to 0 and textboxcell cell to 1 to identify which is being clicked, but no luck. Any advice is aapreciated.

Thanks,

```
I'm adding my code here:
Ignore if a column or row header is clicked
                if (e.RowIndex != -1 && e.ColumnIndex != -1)
                {
                    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
                    {
                        DataGridViewCell clickedCell = (sender as DataGridView).Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];

                        // Here you can do whatever you want with the cell
                        this.dgvAddFilters.CurrentCell = clickedCell;  // Select the clicked cell, for instance


                        // Get mouse position relative to the vehicles grid
                        var relativeMousePosition = dgvAddFilters.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
                        if (clickedCell.Tag.ToString()==null)
                        {
                            return;
                        }
                        else if (imageCell == null) return;
                        else if (e.ColumnIndex == 0 && e.RowIndex == 0)
                        {
                            if ((dgvAddFilters[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex + 2].Value == null))
                            // (dgvAddFilters[e.ColumnIndex + 2, e.RowIndex].Value == null))
                            {
                                dgvAddFilters.ContextMenuStrip = contMenuOr;
                                this.contMenuOr.Show(dgvAddFilters, relativeMousePosition);
                            }
                            else return;
                        }
                        else if ((e.ColumnIndex == 0)
                           && (e.RowIndex > 0)
                           && (dgvAddFilters[e.ColumnIndex + 2, e.RowIndex].Value == null)
                           && (dgvAddFilters[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex + 2].Value == null)
                           && (dgvAddFilters[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value != null))
                        {
                            dgvAddFilters.ContextMenuStrip = contMenuFilterMenu;
                            this.contMenuFilterMenu.Show(dgvAddFilters, relativeMousePosition);
                        }
                        else if ((e.ColumnIndex == 0)
                            && (e.RowIndex > 0)
                            && (dgvAddFilters[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex + 2].Value == null)
                            && (dgvAddFilters[e.ColumnIndex + 2, e.RowIndex].Value != null)
                            && (dgvAddFilters[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value != null))
                        {
                            dgvAddFilters.ContextMenuStrip = contMenuOrEditDelete;
                            this.contMenuOrEditDelete.Show(dgvAddFilters, relativeMousePosition);
                        }
                        else if ((e.ColumnIndex == 0)
                           && (e.RowIndex > 0)
                           && (dgvAddFilters[e.ColumnIndex + 2, e.RowIndex].Value == null)
                           && (dgvAddFilters[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex + 2].Value != null)
                           && (dgvAddFilters[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value != null))
                        {
                            dgvAddFilters.ContextMenuStrip = contMenuAndDeleteEditMenu;
                            this.contMenuAndDeleteEditMenu.Show(dgvAddFilters, relativeMousePosition);
                        }
                        else if ((dgvAddFilters[e.ColumnIndex, (e.RowIndex + 2)] != null)
                            && (dgvAddFilters[(e.ColumnIndex + 2), e.RowIndex].Value != null)
                             && (dgvAddFilters[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value != null))
                        {
                            dgvAddFilters.ContextMenuStrip = contmenuDeletEdit;
                            this.contmenuDeletEdit.Show(dgvAddFilters, relativeMousePosition);
                        }
                        else if ((dgvAddFilters[e.ColumnIndex, (e.RowIndex + 2)] != null)
                            && (dgvAddFilters[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value != null))
                        {
                            dgvAddFilters.ContextMenuStrip = contMenuAndDeleteEditMenu;
                            this.contMenuAndDeleteEditMenu.Show(dgvAddFilters, relativeMousePosition);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            return;
                    }
```

Comment: Can you show the code you're trying to use? It's easier to help if we can see what you're currently doing

Comment: My advice is to read [ask] and take the [tour].  Each column will be a different type so no need for Tags (or luck)

Comment: @Plutonix--Well until stuff works I need a luck :)

Comment: what are you expecting to see happen with `else if (imageCell == null) return;` ? what is `imageCell`?

Answer (score 1):

To know the type of cell that is clicked, You can try below way of doing.... See if it is helpful.

Get the clicked cell and check for its type.

Below is an example to check for checkbox type cell.

```
 private void dataGridView1_CellMouseDown(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
 {
      Type type = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].GetType();

      if (type.Name == "DataGridViewCheckBoxCell")
      {
        string value = (string)dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value;
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this help you?

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace DGVCellTypes_47599159
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        DataGridView dgv = new DataGridView();
        BindingList<dgventry> dgventries = new BindingList<dgventry>();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitOurStuff();
        }

        private void InitOurStuff()
        {
            this.Controls.Add(dgv);
            dgv.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
            dgv.DataSource = dgventries;
            dgv.CellMouseDown += Dgv_CellMouseDown;
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                dgventries.Add(new dgventry { col1 = $"col1_{i}", col2 = $"col2_{i}", col3 = (i % 2) > 0 });
            }
        }

        private void Dgv_CellMouseDown(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
        {

            if (dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex] is DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)
            {
                //do something
            }
            else if (dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex] is DataGridViewTextBoxCell)
            {
                //do something
            }
            else if (dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex] is DataGridViewImageCell)
            {
                //do something
            }
            else
            {
                //do something
            }
        }
    }


    public class dgventry
    {
        public string col1 { get; set; }
        public string col2 { get; set; }
        public bool col3 { get; set; }

    }
}
```

> I'm not getting how to find out whether the current cell is image cell or text box cell

```
        private void Dgv_CellMouseDown(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
        {

            if (dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex] is DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)
            {
                //do something
            }
            else if (dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex] is DataGridViewTextBoxCell)
            {
                //do something
            }
            else if (dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex] is DataGridViewImageCell)
            {
                //do something
            }
            else
            {
                //do something
            }
        }
```

Comment: I think I need something which will give me the value of the clicked cell( I mean if there is image, text or null in the clicked cell)

Comment: @rash dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value will give you value

Comment: Yes It does give me the value. But it does not work for image cell.

Comment: @rash, you'll have to be more specific in regards to what you claim `does not work for image cell`. What is the behavior that tells you it's not working? What is the behavior you are expecting to see?

Comment: @blaze_125 : basically each cell in the datagridview either has image , text or null value. Based the what the value of cell I'm showing different tool tips.

Comment: continued..sorry I accidently hit "Add comment" button before finishing typing

Comment: @blaze_125: I used your second solution to resolve my problem. Thanks for your help. I appreciate it!